Story with hell as a hollow planet
I believe I read this in the late '90s, but it might have been an anthology from the '50s or '60s.
The main topic of the story is that the main character resides in a hollow world where gravity pulls towards the shell of the sphere, with other humans and classical-devil-looking beings (leathery wings etc), all humans convinced they're in hell (or perhaps purgatory?). I believe devils and human communication might have been somewhat limited for some reason.
The main plot twist is

 this is not hell but a kind of pre-life. Advanced aliens realized at some point that even if immortal souls didn't exist they could fabricate them, and then also realized they could avoid wasting a whole life learning how to behave well, and pre-train the souls before incarnation. They did this with the race of devil-like creatures, but then the race went extinct and so they had bunch of spare souls left in the training area when they started training humans. In the end, the human race goes extinct too, and a new kind of alien gets to be soul-trained, in a zero-gravity environment.


Inside Outside, a 1964 novel by Philip José Farmer, which can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the Internet Archive. Humans and demons inside a hollow spherical "hell", but the humans are deceased rather than pre-born. (See update below.) But I haven't read the book, I'm going by the Wikipedia plot summary:

Jack Cull (a pun on the word "jackal") finds himself in a bizarre location called "Hell". A huge sphere with a sun in the center, Hell's population consists of deceased humans and demons; the humans have the same mind and body as when they died, there is no disease or famine, and deaths are reversed within hours. Earthquakes are frequent occurrences. Humans have taken control of Hell, and they have replaced the traditional inscription (as imagined by Dante), "Abandon all hope..." (written in Italian) with a new one: "Do not abandon hope" (written in Hebrew).
Cull goes to his workplace, and hears that the mysterious "X", an analogue of Jesus Christ, has been killed by an unruly mob. Along with Phyllis and Fyodor, based on Fyodor Dostoyevsky, Jack investigates his death. Travelling into a sewer, they find out that "Hell" is in fact a massive spacecraft, controlled by hyper-moral, ultra-powerful alien beings with the means of capturing many if not most of the souls they come upon, incorporating them in immortal bodies (provided they are fed regularly). However, the capturing of souls is an imperfect process, and many souls are lost to the void. Although the bodies are more or less immortal, there comes a time when the aliens destroy them when they feel the souls have progressed to an acceptable level. Even then, not all of the bodies are destroyed, and some continue on with the spaceship as it travels about the galaxy.

Update: The people in the hollow sphere believe they have lived and died and gone to hell, but at the end of the story it's revealed that they have not yet been born:

"T'll tell you, brother, something that will completely shatter you. And make you what it made me, that is a truly demonic creature.
"You thought, after the Immortal spoke to you, that you had lived on Earth and died. And that this was the afterlife prepared for you by the Immortals, a strange sort of Heaven or Hell, to say the least.
"You were wrong! You haven't been born yet!"
[. . . .]
"Calm down. Listen. The Immortals couldn't let well enough alone. Having invented the artificial soul to ensure that all sentients should also bé immortal, they then conceived of pre-birth conditioning. Why not, they said to themselves, build a prenatal world? Give the soul a body such as the soul is likely to have when it attaches itself to the as-yet-unborn body on the natural planet? Give its brain some synthetic memories, so that it thinks it has existed before? And then attempt to install an ethics before it is born?
"The idea was that the creature would have a difficult enough time on Earth; it would find it hard to act ethically, as the Immortals conceive ethics and as much of mankind conceives it. Same as on my planet. It would be a sort of before-Terrestrial-existence reflex conditioning.
"The creature would go through a span of life in this sphere. And, there, through the lectures of the various X's, it would be given a guidance pattern for its next life. This ethical foundation, would, of course, be subconscious. The soul, sent forth again to attach itself to an Earthly body, would have no conscious memories of the pre-Terran life. But there would be an unconscious urging to act ethically."


You know, I was going to say the question sounded like some sort of steampunk version of Riverworld (with the whole "aliens capturing souls" thing, and I guess now I know why.

I had initially accepted this as it seems quite similar, but I'm going to double check the actual text, thanks!

and indeed, it is this one, I have no idea how you managed to find it, but it's the right one, and the plot corresponds to the one I remember, even though summary on wikipedia seems incorrect to me.

@riffraff I have a copy of the book which I bought several decades ago, and I must have read a few pages of the text; enough that your description rang a bell. You're right, at the end it's revealed that the people who think they've died and gone to hell have not been born yet. I will edit my answer accordingly.
